# Upload large files in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, upload

Is it possible to upload large files in Silverlight w/o resorting to the "chunked upload" or loading all of the file data into memmory?

I read something about uploading using Silverlight streaming API, does that work and will it truly stream the data w/o preloading all of it in mem upfront first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silverlight doesn't implement any kind of "stream upload". Before post request goes to the server all data you want to send should be writen into the stream. So if you need to send truly large file I would say  multiple posts with "transfer-encoding: chunked" (i.e chunked upload) is the way to go.

Comment: This isn't a valid answer as SilverLight is not allowed to set the `Transfer-Encoding` header in the WebRequest - [it is set by the browser](https://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/silverlight/2.0/requestheaders.html).

Answer (score 0):

Chunking might help you speed up your uploads as well: [Parallel upload to Azure via Silverlight Control](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Silverlight-Azure-Blob-3b773e26)