# Javascript/flash library that can upload extra large files by splitting (chunking) them

Tags: java, javascript, flash, file-upload, uploadify

[I have already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856916/javascript-flash-library-for-file-upload-with-file-size-limit-and-progress-bar) on javascript/flash libraries for upload, which can make upload of larger files comfortable. However, [there are limits which can disable the upload of larger files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php) (PHP settings like upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, max_input_time etc.), which are sometimes given by your hosting provider.

**Are there any libraries that can chunk (split) the file automatically before upload?**

**EDIT:** found a note in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3112724/684229): "*So if you need to send truly large file I would say multiple posts with "transfer-encoding: chunked" (i.e chunked upload) is the way to go.*"

Comment: another similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891514/javascript-based-library-to-file-chunking-and-file-upload-with-rest-service) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099929/splitting-a-file-before-upload).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help or not. But here is a post I wrote up about using / customizing Plupload. My example also uses the chunking feature of Plupload.

In the post is a link to my example code of it running and chunking files.

http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/plupload-custom-file-upload-ui/

Comment: Looks very good, thanks! Any such example is good, I'm just starting to use plupload.

Comment: Okay cool feel free to email me or comment on the post if you have any more questions!

Comment: Bigamil, thanks - I started to looking at the examples but I have problem from the beginning - [the flash plugin crashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009790/plupload-flash-crashes-when-clicking-on-add-files)! Any thoughts?

Comment: bigamil, no, the very example at http://plupload.com/ is crashing! I reported it as a separate question, see the link I posted in the comment above.

Comment: bigamil, if you would read the link I posted in my 3rd comment you'd see I already reported it... :-) Well, let's clean up this discussion and delete all comments since yesterday (leave only first 3 comments) - I'll delete my last 2 comments if you do the same.

Answer (score 1):

[jClientUpload](http://www.javazoom.net/applets/jclientupload/documentation/installation.html) can do the trick.

Comment: thanks, but where are downloads, releases etc.? I had to download it from [SoftPedia](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php?p=38192&t=0&i=1)... also cannot find licence information, on some download pages it shows that the licence is not free ("shareware" or "free trial")

Answer (score 1):

According to [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4519784/684229), [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) can do it.